# Serialize в PHP

Tags: serialize, массивы, php

вопрос такой - PHP сериализует массив любой степени вложенности, или есть ограничения? на официальном сайте не нашел никакой информации по этому поводу. Может, ссылку какую подкинете. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: все, вопрос исчерпан, все он сериализует. Всем спасибо)) преобразую этот комментарий в ответ когда карма позволит...

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего разработчики не лимитировали ни кол-во полей, ни глубину вложенности. Но при сериализации мега конструкций вы можете вылететь либо по ограничениям памяти, либо по таймауту времени выполнения.

Comment: Согласен, обычно именно это и бывает основной проблемой.

Comment: вот-вот, сейчас именно с этим и борюсь... отгрузка идет по всему году, разной однотипной инфы, но ее там просто очень много (хотя не знаю, можно ли считать большими порядка 30 excel'ей по 150кБ, которые генерятся за один проход скрипта, плюс массивы, которые это хранят), сделал вывод занимаемой памяти - там всего 8мб!!!...блин, про таймаут я не подумал, еще одно спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

В чем суть вопроса? Вылезла ошибка? Может быть вылезет ошибка?

Что для тебя большое кол-во вложенности? 10-50-100?

Нужно используй. Или напиши правильно вопрос, который будет более развернут. Допустим ты хочешь написать статью, где не нужно использовать serialize т.к. он вернёт ошибку при вложенности более 100.

Comment: нет, все в порядке, люди, спасибо. Просто не печатался массив после unserialize(), но это я где-то еще натупил, а сначала были подозрения по поводу того что сериализация сериализует массив не целиком. и нет, там меньше 50 уровней подвложенности, такие пока не нужны массивы)))